# How to iterate over JSON Array in Swift using Codable & Hashable

Tags: arrays, json, swift, parsing, codable

New to iOS dev and had much success earlier learning about views & animations. However, I am having trouble figuring out how to parse my JSON. My main goal is to have parameters for verse(s) and chapter(s) and a return string. I spent a day learning about Swift Dictionary Mapping, but decided Codeable Mapping is an easier method.

*Problem 1*

Getting Bible.self from the data works great (I am able to print all), but trying to decode [Chapters].self and [Verses].self results in nil, and therefore the catch error. Why is this the case?

*Problem 2*

The chapter and verse JSON fields are strings, could this cause issues later when, for example, retrieving multiple verses? I know there are a lot of useful JSON tools to change these strings to int if so. Otherwise I am hoping 'Hashable' could work.

*Problem 3*

My biggest issue is with my JSONoutput. I believe I need a loop inside a loop (chapter / verse). Is there an easier way to fetch certain strings in the JSON?

**JSON Code (a snippet):**

```
    {
  "book": "Jude",
  "chapters": [
    {
      "chapter": "1",
      "verses": [
        {
          "verse": "1",
          "text": "Jude, the servant of Jesus Christ, and brother of James, to them that are sanctified by God the Father, and preserved in Jesus Christ, and called:"
        },
        {
          "verse": "2",
          "text": "Mercy unto you, and peace, and love, be multiplied."
        },
        {
          "verse": "3",
          "text": "Beloved, when I gave all diligence to write unto you of the common salvation, it was needful for me to write unto you, and exhort you that ye should earnestly contend for the faith which was once delivered unto the saints."
        }]}]} //it continues on...
```

**My structs**

```
struct Bible : Codable, Hashable {
    let book : String
    let chapters : [Chapters]
}

struct Chapters : Codable, Hashable {
    let chapter : String
    let verses : [Verses]
}

struct Verses : Codable, Hashable {
    let verse : String
    let text : String
}
```

**My Code**

```
func readJSONFromFile(fileName: String, getChapters: String, getVerses: String) -> String
{
    var JSONoutput: String = ""
    
    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: "json") else {return ""}

    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    
    guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url, options: .mappedIfSafe) else {return ""}
                        
    
    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let bible = try decoder.decode(Bible.self, from: data)
        
        // the following give erros...
        // let chapters = try decoder.decode([Chapters].self, from: data)
        // let verses = try decoder.decode([Verses].self, from: data)
        
        // return:
        // JSONoutput = for x in BLANK {} ...
    }
    catch
    {
        print("error in parsing")
    }
    
    return JSONoutput
}
```

Comment: Remove those lines it's already stored in the top-level object. You can directly access chapter and verses this way:         print(bible.chapters) // prints all chapters
        print(bible.chapters.first?.verses) // prints all verses in chapter 1

Comment: Problem 1: The structure of your JSON matches that of `Bible`, so you need to decode it into `Bible`. The JSON decoder is not going to automatically retrieve nested objects (e.g, the `Verse` object) from the JSON data and decode it into those types. You must do that yourself.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Explain why.

Comment: You misunderstood what I said. What I meant is that you cannot *directly* decode `[Verse]` from the JSON data using a JSONDecoder if `[Verse]` is nested inside another object. For example, look at the original post: `verses = try decoder.decode([Verses].self, from: data)`. This doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The Bible object you get back when decoding will contain all the chapters and verses so you don’t need to decode anything else.

You can change the decoding function like this

```
func readJSONFromFile(fileName: String) -> Bible? {    
    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: "json") else { return nil }
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)   
    guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url, options: .mappedIfSafe) else { return nil }
                            
    do {      
        return try JSONDecoder().decode(Bible.self, from: data)        
    } catch {
        print("error in parsing: \(error)")
        return nil 
    }
}
```